# Nagios bizare ping behaviour

Tags: networking, nagios, ping

I have nagios setup as I want it, but last night it started alerting me of a problem pinging the internet. (I have a check that pings www.google.com to test that the internet is still working)

Now looking into this problem I can see that my network can ping the internet fine, the server that runs nagios can also ping the internet but if I run

```
./check_ping -H www.google.com -w -c
```

I get Network Unreachable

but

```
./check_ping -H [IP address of google] -w -c
```

I get ping OK

I can use ping on both ip and domain name and they both work fine.

Anyone got any clues as to where the problem lies, is it nagios or do I have a problem with DNS in my nagios box or in my network somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you do "host www.google.com"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Same thing happened to us last night starting at about 20:01 EDT, and the alert is still not functioning properly.  I hadn't tried running the check_ping with one of Google's IP addresses until I read your post though, and it worked here just as it did for you.  `ping www.google.com` returns successful pings, and I can browse to www.google.com from my nagios server as well, but the check_ping monitor is still critical.

-- fixed-for-me --

I found that the `ping6 www.google.com` command failed immediately with a network unreachable error, while a `ping www.google.com` succeeded.  I ran the check_ping command as before with www.google.com adding a -4 flag at the end to force it to use IPV4, and the check_ping now succeeds.

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H www.google.com -w 100.0,20% -c 200.0,40% -4
PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 22.51 ms
```

So I edited the commands.cfg file to add a -4 to the end of the command, and voila, a successful check.

Comment: Glad to here I am not alone, which suggests that it might not be my network this time that is the problem

Comment: On debian, the nagios-plugins-basic package (provder of the `check-host-alive` definition) also defines `check-host-alive_4`.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you're participating in the [IPv6 day](http://www.ipv6day.org/) and the [IPv6 launch of the "most important internet sites"](http://www.indyposted.com/148032/google-facebook-yahoo-to-launch-world-ipv6-day/). You are probably pinging a v6 site address when using the name without having v6 connectivity at your Nagios server. The good news is that it is over by midnight :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this problem is to use

```
check_command                   check-host-alive_4
```

in *host* definition.

*check-host-alive_4* is defined in */etc/nagios-plugins/config/ping.cfg* (in Ubuntu 14.04) specially for occasions described by Shawn Maceno above.